# Is there a way to autogenerate the required app images for the Apple iStore?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to create a new listing for an a iOS app.
One of the requirements is to provide the relevant screenshots.

[image]

Is there any way that I can autogenerate these images of my application, as oppose to creating a emulator and doing the screenshots manually.